# migration from springMVC+springscurity to AngularJS+springscurity+springMVC

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am currently working for migrating springmvc application into angularjs based(main intention was use pure html based frame work instead JSP).

It is login based and it use spring security. I got nice examples but I stuck in use of http session and session timeout

https://github.com/philipsorst/angular-rest-springsecurity  - using cookie to store session.

another good example with demo

https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2016/01/25/secure-angularjs-application-with-spring-security/

above example it use java based configuration instead spring-context.xml, spring-security.xml and web.xml . So it is hard for me map with my current set ups of xmls.

Any input of this? any example which use xml based configuration for angularjs+spring security?

Answer (score 0):

[AngularJS Bootstrap with Spring](https://github.com/Robert-Leggett/angular_bootstrap_spring)